# Retrieve data in Couchbase Lite without JSON

Tags: json, couchbase-lite

How to retrieve data from DB having a particular key in Couchbase Lite without JSON?(IOS Framework)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We dont have json data.The whole Object is there with 4 fields(No key value).I have tried using key,startkey,endkey in the rest API and emit function.May be emit could be used but i am unable to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expound on question. Ideally you would use a model object, but that stores everything as JSON. Remember that any sort of data can be stored in JSON, so even if it has a little bit of overhead in the end it is the easiest to work with.

If this is a more complicated architecture question, you may want to post on the official Couchbase forum on their website, where their technicians can answer.